# Is it possible to run javascript as cgi script on Apache?

Tags: javascript, apache, cgi

I managed to configure my Apache to run cgi scripts and I tried to use javascript to generate output.

```
#!C:\php\php.exe

<script>
  document.write("Hello world!");
</script>
```

However this only sends the contents and the `document.write` is run on the client. I'd like to send *Hello world!* by javascript.

I know there is nodejs. I wonder if there is a module for Apache or some settings that enables running javascript on the server and send only the contents of `document.write`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGI explicitly spawns an external process, so would use `mod_cgi`. You could then spawn a Node.js process.

You would, however, need to write a real CGI program and not use a fragment of HTML with embedded JS that depends on browser APIs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

process.stdout.write("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n");
process.stdout.write("Hello, world");
```

CGI isn't very efficient, and Node would be an odd choice of language. If you need to go via Apache then it would usually make more sense to run a server using Node and then use mod_proxy to access it via Apache.